# 2 problems with dealing with UITextField behind Keyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, keyboard, scroll, uitextfield

I have a UITextField in my UITableViewCell in my view. Now there is a possibility that the UITextField can be behind my Keyboard so I properly deal with that using the following two methods. One is for when the keyboard is clicked and the other is when it is dismissed:

```
- (void)keyboardNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[[tempTextField superview] superview];
    CGRect textFieldRect = [cell convertRect:tempTextField.frame toView:self.view];
    if (textFieldRect.origin.y + textFieldRect.size.height >= [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - keyboardSize.height) {
        thetableView.contentInset =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0);
        NSIndexPath *pathOfTheCell = [thetableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        [thetableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:pathOfTheCell.row inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    }

}

- (void)keyboardhideNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    thetableView.contentInset =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Now it works somewhat well however there are 2 issues.

1. The tableview only scrolls to above the keyboard if the ENTIRE UITextField is below the top of the keyboard. If the keyboard is halfway up the UITextField that is being selected, the tableview will not scroll to above the keyboard. From a quick glance it looks like this should work but I may be missing something.

2
. When the keyboard is below the keyboard and the tableview scrolls up, it does so in a nice animated fashion however when I click done it just immediately pops back to the old position. I can obviously see why this is happening but how would I make the nice animation to revert back to the old position the tableview was in?

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:** I managed to find the issue for #1. It was a silly mistake. Should have added the height of the textField to the origin since that measurement is going downward. Now onto #2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code simply fixed both 1 and 2:

```
- (void)keyboardNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[[tempTextField superview] superview];
    CGRect textFieldRect = [tempTextField convertRect:tempTextField.frame toView:self.view];
    if (textFieldRect.origin.y + textFieldRect.size.height >= [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - keyboardSize.height) {
        NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
        NSNumber *number = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
        double duration = [number doubleValue];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
            thetableView.contentInset =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0);
        }];
        NSIndexPath *pathOfTheCell = [thetableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        [thetableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:pathOfTheCell.row inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
    }

}

- (void)keyboardhideNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    NSNumber *number = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    double duration = [number doubleValue];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        thetableView.contentInset =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }];
}
```